# HSQL Iterated FOR Statement not working

Tags: hsqldb

Using HSQL 2.2.5 I need to *shudder* process one row at a time in a stored procedure, so I thought the "Iterated FOR" statement might do the trick for me. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to make it work. It's supposed to look something like:

FOR SELECT somestuff FROM sometable DO
   some random SQL statements
END FOR;

That leaves off a bit of the syntax, but it's close enough for now.

The problem seems to be that the statements inside the loop never execute. I've verified that my SELECT statement does indeed return something.

So let's get concrete. When I execute this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE b()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
   DECLARE count_var INTEGER;
   SET count_var = 0;
   WHILE count_var < 10 DO
      INSERT INTO TTP2 VALUES(count_var);
      SET count_var = count_var + 1;
   END WHILE;
END;
```

I get 10 rows inserted into table TTP2, with values 0 through 9. (TTP2 has just one column defined, of type INTEGER.)

But when I substitute a FOR statement for the WHILE like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE c()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
   DECLARE count_var INTEGER;
   SET count_var = 0;
   FOR SELECT id FROM ttp_by_session FETCH 10 ROWS ONLY DO
      INSERT INTO TTP2 VALUES(count_var);
      SET count_var = count_var + 1;
   END FOR;
END;
```

I get nothing inserted into TTP2. (I have verified that the SELECT statement returns 10 rows, one column of integers.)

When I leave the FETCH clause off I still get no results. ttp_by_session is a view, but the same thing happens with a bare table.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine with the latest version of HSQLDB. Try with the 2.3.0 release candidate snapshot from the HSQLDB web site.

When the FOR statement was initially added about two years ago, it had limited functionality. The functionality was extended in later versions.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I'll give that a shot and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: I downloaded 2.2.9 (wanted a stable release). It works as advertised. :-) Thanks @fredt!